# Не могу отобразить данные после считывания из папки

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Помогите, пожалуйста, начинающему Data Scientist.
На компьютере есть папка, из которой считываю данные. 
Считывание проходит вроде-как без ошибок, но когда вывожу переменную, получаю ошибку. 
Вот код:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files 
import os
PATH_TO_DATA = 'C:/Users/ivan1/Downloads/imdb_reviews/'
%%time
train_reviews = load_files(os.path.join(PATH_TO_DATA, 'train'))
```

Результат:

```
Wall time: 12.9 s
```

Далее делаю:

```
len(train_reviews.data)
```

Ошибка:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cfae4af4e1ec> in <module>
----> 1 len(train_reviews.data)

NameError: name 'train_reviews' is not defined
```

В чем может быть причина этого? 
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Причина в использовании `%%time`, переменная `train_reviews` не сохраняется.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)